# Wanted: SSL certificate analyzer

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a server that needs to work with SSL. We're having some problems with the SSL certificates. Does anybody know a good certificate analyzer that can tell me what is wrong?

It is an internal server, so I can't use an online test site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently got some certificates from GeoTrust and used their checker [here](https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=SO9557&actp=LIST) to make sure everything was working - unsure if it will work with certificates from other authorities.

Comment: The server can't go beyond the firewall... so an online tool is out of the question.

Comment: Ah... it's a Java tool :-) handy

Answer (score 2):

Openssl commands will help you to find out details of SSL certs. Check this link.

http://techtrunch.com/commands/checking-ssl-certs-validity-details

Answer (score 2):

You may use openssl to check a host's ssl certificate (+chain) and tell you what it thinks is wrong with it:

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some free online test tools out there.

E.g. http://www.ssltest.net/

Comment: The server can't go beyond the firewall... so an online tool is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Describe the problems with SSL? There's lots of stuff that can go wrong, from CRL locations being inaccessible (for Internet-blocked servers) to, well, just about anything.

Simplest in-box mechanism is typically to open the certificate in the certificates MMC.

- Every certificate you need to use needs an associated private key. There's text at the bottom of the General properties page that indicates whether you do or not.
- For servers, the certificate needs an intended purpose that includes Server Authentication.

If that looks OK, proceed to `CERTUTIL -verify certfile.cer`  (potentially throw in -urlfetch as well).

But again: describe the problems, cos that'll point to possible solutions.